# How to getelementbyclass?

Tags: javascript

Below is my Code. I have a search query that returns a list of items in a list with a popup link that should display data relevant to which was clicked. The problem I have is that I am using `getElementById` and it cannot by reused, so when the popup function is multiplied amongst all items of the list, The popup only displays data relevant to the first item in the list.

```
function pop() {
    var x = document.getElementById('popup');
    x.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the `pop` function?

Comment: I think a *popup* should only present one item at once.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code and how you are using it?

Answer (score 2):

Make the function generic. If you're calling it through an event handler then you can reformat your `pop` function like this:

```
function pop() {
    this.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Nice reputation score. Don't want to spoil :)

Comment: @VisioN Please feel free. :)

Comment: Was thinking the same thing! Onwards to 7,777